# Type inference of generic T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-7.0

I have the following piece of code:

```
public interface IVector<T>
{
    static abstract int Length { get; }
    ref T this[int index] { get; }
}

public static class VectorExtensions
{
    public static TElement LengthSquared<TVector, TElement>(this TVector vector)
        where TVector : IVector<TElement>
        where TElement : INumberBase<TElement>
    {
        TElement lengthSquared = TElement.Zero;

        for (int i = 0; i < TVector.Length; ++i)
        {
            lengthSquared += vector[i] * vector[i];
        }

        return lengthSquared;
    }

    public static TElement Length<TVector, TElement>(this TVector vector)
        where TVector : IVector<TElement>
        where TElement : INumberBase<TElement>, IRootFunctions<TElement>
    {
        return TElement.Sqrt(vector.LengthSquared());
    }
}
```

Which sadly produces the following error in the second method:

> The type arguments for method 'VectorExtensions.LengthSquared<TVector,
> TElement>(TVector)' cannot be inferred from the usage.

Is there a way to structure this code so that it can infer the type of `TElement`?

Comment: You're not passing `TElement` in as a parameter, so it can't be inferred. Inference only works when it's a parameter and can deduce it from that. AFAIK

Comment: so you need to provide both type-parameters: `vector.LemgthSquared<TVector, TElement>()`.

Comment: Why do you even need the `TVector` type?  Just do `this IVector<TElement>`.

Comment: Why is the `Length` defined as static?  Do you really want all Vectors with the same generic type to have the same length?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK C# always struggled a little bit with type inference for multiple generic type parameters, so you need either to specify them explicitly:

```cs
return TElement.Sqrt(vector.LengthSquared<TVector, TElement>());
```

Or add second parameter of `TElement` to `LengthSquared`:

```
public static TElement LengthSquared<TVector, TElement>(
    this TVector vector, 
    TElement _) // some parameter to infer type
    where TVector : IVector<TElement>
    where TElement : INumberBase<TElement>
{
    TElement lengthSquared = TElement.Zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < TVector.Length; ++i)
    {
        lengthSquared += vector[i] * vector[i];
    }

    return lengthSquared;
}

public static TElement Length<TVector, TElement>(this TVector vector)
    where TVector : IVector<TElement>
    where TElement : INumberBase<TElement>, IRootFunctions<TElement>
{
    return TElement.Sqrt(vector.LengthSquared(TElement.Zero));
}
```

Comment: Better yet, remove the `TVector` type and just use `this IVector<TElement>`

Comment: @juharr code uses static `TVector.Length` so unless there would instance counterpart then it can't be done.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it does not help as far as I can see.

Comment: Having the length of a Vector be static also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @juharr it depends. I would say that it can make sense for stuff like `Vector3`, `Vector4`, ...

Comment: Still wouldn't need to be static as you'd just define it as `public int Length => 3;` or `public int Length => 4;`  you'd only need it to be static if you wanted to get the length of a type without creating an instance and that doesn't seem very useful.